# How to make pandas recognise my xlsx file as multiple-columned datafrane

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: My xlsx file I made by myself for bot permissions]

While making my bot to set permissions automatically while it came into a guild, Writing codes for this seemed getting too long. So, I just wanted to made my bot to get xlsx file as dataframe and set permissions from that data inside.

I wanted to make this xlsx file of mine as multiple-columned dataframe, but I don't think my program recognises it as one. Do I have my errors in my code below or I have to change my excel file for it to be rocognised as I wanted?

```
from pandas import read_excel

perm_data = read_excel('E:/Discord bot/Grail-Relique/data/xlsx/TextPermission.xlsx', header=[0,1], engine='openpyxl')
print(perm_data)
print(perm_data.loc[0,(0,0)])
```

[result](https://pastebin.com/P0REfFBc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('your/path/to/file.xlsx', 
                   header=[0,1], 
                   index_col=0)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: What I wanted to get from `print(perm_data.loc[0,(0,0)])` was to make sure that this was checking if pandas read it as multiple-column dataframe by getting a value from it

Comment: index_col should have been just 0 to function properly as intended cuz I wanted to get was just first column as index.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Haidus. I've just edited the answer to meet more specifically your requirements :)